# Как вытащить данные osm с postgreSQL чтобы отобразить карты leaflet без интернета на локальном сайте

Tags: javascript, php, openstreetmap

У меня данные из osm лежат на базе PostgreSQL и я хочу вытащить данные оттуда, чтобы затем показывать на карте leaflet у себя на локальном сайте без интернета. Как мне это сделать?